# Cross Domain with frames

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, frame, same-origin-policy, frameset

I have one html page with url :

```
http://server1/phone_app
```

which loads a frames from the url:

```
http://server2/directory_app
```

in the contained frame (directory_app), I need the displayed URL in the browser which is actually (`http://server1/phone_app`).
Unfortunately, i have no access to the container page, and because of the "**same origin policy**", i can't access the `window.top.location.href`.

Is there any way to do this?

Browser : IE7

Comment: You mean you want to have the url of the contained page displayed in the browser address bar? If so, you can't do this. Well you can, but then the iframe url will load.

Comment: actually No. In the contained frame, i must know which server i am interacting with. this information exists in the url displayed in the browser which is the url of the container page(http://server1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot read data from other domains (except via things like JSON-P which are not applicable in this situation).

You could pass in details into the frame via the query string:

```
src="http://server2/directory_app?a=b;x=y"
```